# Explicit example of holomorphic function with property

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is from Stein and Shakarchi, Ch. 3 Ex. 16:

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a region containing the disc $|z|\leq 1$.  Suppose that $f$ has a simple pole at $z=0$ and vanishes nowhere else in $|z|\leq 1$.  Let $$f_\epsilon(z)=f(z)+\epsilon g(z)$$  Show that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then
>   1) $f_\epsilon$ has a unique zero in $|z|\leq 1$, and
>   2)
>   if $z_\epsilon$ is this zero, the mapping $\epsilon\mapsto z_\epsilon$ is continuous.

I don't need help with the proof of the two questions, I'm wondering if anyone has an explicit example of a function fulfilling $f$'s properties.  Per the Maximum Modulus principle, the minimum of $f$ must occur on its boundary, so the simple zero at $z=0$ isn't the minimum.  So $|f|$ must go from positive to negative at $z=0$ while maintaining holomorphicity.  For whatever reason, this seems odd to me/hard to imagine.

So, does anyone know any explicit examples, or ways that it can make more sense intuitively?

Comment: Use Rouché's theorem.

Comment: @carmichael561: The question (as I understand it) is not how to prove the theorem, but why $f$ does not violate the maximum modulus principle. Of course I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

> Suppose that $f$ has a simple pole at $z=0$ ...

should be

> Suppose that $f$ has a simple *zero* at $z=0$ ...

Concrete examples would be $f(z) = z$, $f(z) = z(z-2)$
or generally, any $f(z) = z  F(z)$ where $F$ is holomorphic and not zero in a neighborhood of $\lvert z \rvert \le 1$.

Your statement

> Per the Maximum Modulus principle, the minimum of $|f|$ must occur on its boundary ...

is not correct. It follows from the maximum modulus principle that
the *maximum* of $|f|$ is attained at the boundary. If $f$ were *non-zero*
in the given domain then you could apply the maximum modulus principle
to $1/f$ and conclude that the minimum of $|f|$ is also attained at
the boundary.

However, $f$ has a zero, $1/f$ is not holomorphic and you 
cannot apply the maximum modulus principle to $1/f$.
There is no contradiction, the minimum of $|f|$ is attained at $z=0$
because $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding!